# importing a JPEG image into an IPython (notebook) program

Tags: python, pygame, ipython

I'm using a IPython notebook to write a program using pygame library. Here, I want to import an image file to the programme. Following is the code piece I would have used.

```
car = pygame.image.load('car.jpg')
```

But to do this, the image has to be in the same directory as the python file. Where are these IPython notebook files saved? Or is there any other way I can import this file to program in IPython notebook?

I'm using windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are an number of ways to change directories or specify full paths:

- [IPython understands](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/reference.html#magic-command-system) the `cd` command to change directories (if 'automagic' is enabled; use `%cd` if not), or
- use [os.chdir](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.chdir), or
- specify a path:

  ```
  load('/path/to/car.jpg')
  ```

  or

  ```
  import os
  load(os.path.expanduser('~/path/to/car.jpg')) # relative to user's home directory
  ```

  or

  ```
   IMAGEDIR = '/path/to/images'
   load(os.path.join(IMAGEDIR, 'car.jpg'))
  ```

Although `cd` is convenient while working in IPython, for your program you are better off specifying a full path to `car.jpg`.